# script to parse a directory and rename with the same name and change only extension (after converting using sphinx)

Tags: scripts, extension

I am using `pocketsphinx` to convert audio file to text. These two commands must do the work:

First i run

```
ffmpeg -i file.mp3 -ar 16000 -ac 1 file.wav
```

then i run

```
pocketsphinx_continuous -infile file.wav 2> pocketsphinx.log > result.txt
```

I do that for each file (mp4 or mp3), I want to execute these two commands only once in a script, by browsing the directory content (files with the extension mp3 or mp4), and give the file the same name with the extension .txt (for exemple with the first command "file.mp3" become "file.wav" then using the second command "file.wav" become "file.txt").

How to do that using a single script file?

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

dir=$1

for path in "$dir"/*.mp3; do
  name=$(basename "$path")
  ffmpeg -i "$path" -ar 16000 -ac 1 "$dir/$name.wav"
  pocketsphinx_continuous -infile "$dir/$name.wav" 2> "$dir/pocketsphinx.log" > "$dir/$name.txt"
done
```

Save the script somewhere like `convert_all.sh` and `chmod +x` it as well. Then use it like this:

```
./convert_all.sh path/to/some/dir
```

It will get all the .mp3s in that directory, convert them to .wav then run sphinx on them.